# VueJS & Webpack: ENV var unaccessible from built project

Tags: docker, webpack, vue.js, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm working on an app with vuejs frontend and nodejs backend. My frontend makes API https requests to the backend. I've started my projet with vue-cli and webpack.
I need to get the backend API url from env variable (BACKEND_URL).
Since i'm using webpack, I added this line to config/prod.env.js :

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
 -> BACKEND_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.BACKEND_URL)
}
```

It works flawlessly in dev mode using webpack-dev-server. I pass the env var throught docker-compose file:

```
environment:
            - BACKEND_URL=https://whatever:3000
```

But when I run build, I use nginx to serve the static files (but the problem is the same using visual studio code live server extension). I send  BACKEND_URL env var the same way as before. The thing is now the process.env.BACKEND_URL is undefined in the app (but defined in the container)!! So I cant make backend http calls :(
I'm struggling finding the problem, please don't be rude with the responses. Thank you

Comment: I think you need to keep env variable in .env file. You could have `url.env` which has content `BACKEND_URL=https://whatever:3000` and then in docker-compose you add a line `env_file: -url.env` . see if that helps . The formatting is not quite right for docker-compose. you probably know how it is.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The problem isn't there: When I enter a container with docker exec /bin/bash, and printenv, the BACKEND_URL is there. The problem is that the webpack compiled project can no longer read the env var.

Answer (score 4):

They aren not "translated" during build time, this is what is happening with you. On a node environment, when you ask for `process.env` it will show all environment variables available in the system, that is true. But a web application does not have access to `process.env` when it is executing. You need a way to translate them during build time.

To achieve that you have to use [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx). It translates anything during build time and writes a magical string where this other thing was.

Using you own example:

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  BACKEND_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.BACKEND_URL)
}
```

If you do this during build time, without DefinePlugin, webpack won't know what to do with it, and it is going to be a simple string.

If you use DefinePlugin:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env.BACKEND_URL": JSON.stringify(process.env.BACKEND_URL)
});
```

By doing this, you are allowing webpack to translate this during build time.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me understand what's happening. I actually have the exact same syntax you advise me. So as I understand, by doing this webpack will only take the env var value during build time. So if the BACKEND_URL changes, I have no way for frontend to know but to rebuild my app to take the change into account. I would have loved if my app could read env var before each request I need to make to the backend.

Comment: Nop, it is not possible, they run in different "environments", so on the webpack it cannot get process.env

Answer (score 3):

Give this a shot: https://www.brandonbarnett.io/blog/2018/05/accessing-environment-variables-from-a-webpack-bundle-in-a-docker-container/

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you're serving a webpack bundle using nginx, and trying to access an environment variable from that bundle.

Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work that way. Your JS file has no access to the environment since it's a resource that has been delivered to the client. I've proposed a solution that also delivers those env variables alongside the bundle in a separate JS file that gets created on container start.

Answer (score 2):

From VueJS Docs: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

## **Using Env Variables in Client-side Code**

Only variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin. You can access them in your application code:

```
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET)
```

During build, process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET will be replaced by the corresponding value. In the case of VUE_APP_SECRET=secret, it will be replaced by "secret".

---

So in your case, the following should do the trick. I had the same problem once in my project, which I started with vue/cli and `vue create project ...`

```
VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL=https://whatever:3000
```

Comment: completely unrelated to the question

Comment: Care to explain how this is "completely unrelated" to the question ? @Z

Comment: Because this problem is the classic "i can't access env variables at runtime from static html": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010064/pass-environment-variable-into-a-vue-app-at-runtime